# Tuning when changing strings

Tags: guitar, tuning, strings

I just recently ordered a set of Cleartones Monster Drop C strings (13-70). I was wondering, as I change them, should I tune them straight to drop C or should I still bring them up to standard tuning and then adjust them afterwards?

Comment: Those thick string will be very difficult to play at a normal tuning.

Comment: Just a friendly reminder: be prepared to adjust your intonation, and possibly widen the string slots in the nut. Even worse will be if them big bugger strings won't fit through the hole in your tuner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they are specifically for a dropped tuning, tuning up to standard might be a risk of breaking your brand new strings.

Perhaps check the packaging to see if they can be used with a standard tuning. If not, don't tune them all the way up.

Answer (score 3):

The point of thicker strings for drop C tuning is that they will end up at about the same tension as the original set at concert pitch. So the neck, bridge and belly of the guitar (and the new set of strings) are only stressed the same as they were originally. Take them up to standard at your peril!!